# Win32 ListBox WNDPROC never called

Tags: c++, winapi, listbox, wndproc

I am writing a fairly simple wrapper around Win32 controls/dialogs/windows.

The issue I have is that ListBox's and ComboBox's seem to behave rather differently.

In the base Widget class that I am inheriting from, I override the existing WNDPROC for the control and then handle messages in the new WNDPROC, primarily promoting them to boost::signal events.

The issue is that, while ComboBox's WndProc receives the CBN_SELCHANGE - as expected - ListBox's WndProc does not receive the LBN_SELCHANGE command.

I realize that the dialog/window that owns the control will likely receive this, but I've kind of gone down this rabbit hole already and it feels like a pretty neat solution. Need I back out and have the owners of the controls handle the WM_COMMAND messages (and from there promote it to an event on the control itself).

This is a learning exercise, so please don't remind me about MFC or comment on the value of doing this.

Comment: Did you turn on the LBS_NOTIFY style?  You can't ignore that the WM_COMMAND message is sent to the parent.

Comment: Yes, with LBS_NOTIFY the owning dialog is informed of ListBox WM_COMMANDs. However, the ComboBox's own WNDPROC is notified of these, too, so I was thinking the ListBox's WNDPROC would be similarly notified, but apparently not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notification messages are typically sent to a control's parent.  Presumably all the windows (i.e. both parent windows and controls) are using the same window procedure?  In this case the usual solution is: in the notification handler in your window procedure check if the notification came from the current window.  If it did, raise an event; if it didn't resend the message back to the control it came from (where it will be raised as an event).

Comment: Yeah, I figure I'm going to just have to accept that the dialog / window that owns the control needs to forward the command on to the control itself. Not ideal, because it means that the control is not as encapsulated as I would have liked, but I suppose it's the best I'm going to get under the circumstances.

Comment: Plumbing is always a bit messy.  From the point of view of application code the encapsulation is perfect.  Seems pretty good to me.